# Chrome Extension: Getting error: Unrecognized manifest key 'start_url'

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, manifest.json

Working on a Chrome extension and creating a manifest.json file

Based on the Chrome documents the "start_url" exists (and is documented) https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/#start-url

But I'm getting the error "Unrecognized manifest key 'start_url'". Obviously, I can remove that key and 'fix' the error, but I want the ability to 'tell the browser where your application should start when it is launched...direct the user straight into your app, rather than a product landing page. Think about the what the user will want to do once they open your app, and place them there" (which is what the start_url key is supposed to do)

Is there another way to achieve this that isn't documented? Is my syntax wrong somehow?

```
  {
    "start_url": "/start", // the page I want the app to open on
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "My Extension",
    "description": "A fantastic extension",
    "short_name": "Extension",
    "version": "1.0",
    "background": {
      "scripts": [
        "events.js"
      ],
      "persistent": true
    },
      "browser_action": {
      "default_popup": "index.html",
      "default_title": "Extension"
    },
    "content_scripts": [
      {
        "matches": ["*://*/*"],
        "css": [],
        "js": ["content.js"]
      }
    ]
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

A [progressive web app](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Progressive) is not the same thing as an extension; they're different in every way imaginable, including the manifest.

Here's the [Manifest File Format](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest) for extensions.

Furthermore, a Chrome extension isn't "launched" like you would an app — it has several entry points that can be activated at various times, like clicking on the browser action to open a popup, or a context menu item, or a content script that runs on certain pages, or a background page that opens a tab in response to certain conditions.

Comment: Thanks! I guess I was mixing up the documentations for manifests